# C# SQL Server 'Use <Database>' Required when "Initial Catalog' specified in COnnection String

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a connection string to connect to a database in C#.  Which works and I am able to read/write to the database.  However I am trying to get table names using the command

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = FC_TABLE;
```

When I use this command in SQL Server query I have to point to DB using 'USE DatabaseName GO' which is all well and good.  If not then it queries Master and I get a return value that is empty.

However when I use this string in C# SqlReader I have already set the 'Initial Catalog' to the database I would normall point to with USE in my connection string so shouldn't it default there?  I am getting the same empty return value but can't figure out why unless I have to use USE.  But I am not having problems writing data otherwise.

Comment: What is `DATASET` in your query?

Comment: It is the name of the table, I actuall renamed to FC_Table to prevent any confusion, I'll do that in the question to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. `piv` is my table name

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=temp;User ID=sa"))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'piv';";

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string x = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Cheers, I was using reader.GetName(i) in a for loop, not sure why that didn't work, probably should have put that in my question.  Anyway, this works.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this. Remove GO and terminate query with semi colon;

```
var sql =@" Use Master
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME =@FC_DATASET;"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FC_Dataset",yourTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

`USE DATABASE_NAME` is used in SQL Query editor where all the code line below to the `USE` statement would execute in that particular database. Creating connection string with a specific database in C# allows user to do operations only to that database unless you not mentioned any database explicitly in your query.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server=.;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=MyDB"))
        {
            string query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Resource';";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
```